# Concatenating 3 strings the outcome changes randomly

Tags: excel, vba, listobject, excel-tables

New to VBA coding and 1st time that I'm asking something, so give some slack if you see some dummy code.

I have an Excel Table which in column A has dates in the mm/dd/year format. I want to change it to dd/mm/year and in order to make some practice in VBA, I tried to do it via code (i have tried the Format Cells options but didn't work).
For a start I'm trying to rewrite the Date column in column H with the desired format using the following code:

```
Public Sub ChangingDateFormat()

    Dim dest As Range
    Dim dindx As Integer
    Dim cll As Range
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String
    Dim z As String
   
    'Establish where output goes
    Set dest = Range("H2")
    
    'Set counter for output rows
    dindx = 0
    
    'Establish your North Star reference
    Set cll = Range("A2")
    
    'Loop as long as anchor cell down isn't blanc
    While cll.Offset(dindx, 0) <> ""
        
        'Test if not empty; if not empty populate destination with data
        If cll.Offset(dindx, 0) <> "" Then
        
            x = Left(cll.Offset(dindx, 0), 2)
            y = Mid(cll.Offset(dindx, 0), 4, 3)
            z = Right(cll.Offset(dindx, 0), 5)
            
            'True case: Output date
            dest.Offset(dindx, 0) = y & x & z
            
            'Increment row counter
            dindx = dindx + 1
                
         End If
         
    'End While statement
    Wend
    
End Sub
```

However, when the macro runs, some cells have the desired format and others not.

The Excel sheet looks like this:

[My WorkSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWVhM.png)

Any ideas where the problem is? Pointing me to a direction would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use [`DateSerial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateserial-function) instead of concatenating.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Format` function like that (This is just sample) and try to implement in your code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1")
    r.Offset(, 3).Value = Format(r.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Excel Table (`ListObject`)

- The following covers only the part *I have an Excel Table which in column A has dates in the mm/dd/year format. I want to change it to dd/mm/year...* i.e. the values in column `A` are real dates, not text.
- Adjust the sheet and table names appropriately.
- Since you are dealing with a [ListObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject) (Table), you might consider using its properties.
- The following procedures show how you can exploit some of them in two cases.
- The first procedure will change the **number format** in the first column of the table, (not necessarily the first column of the worksheet). It is used when a column is always the first, so the header (title) can be changed.
- The second procedure will try to find the given header (`Header`). If successful, it will apply the **number formatting** to the column where the header was found. It is used when the header (title) will never change, but the position of the column in the table might.

**The Code**

```
Sub IOnlyKnowTheColumnNumber()
    
    ' The n-th column of the Table, not the worksheet.
    Const DateColumn As Long = 1
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    ' Define Date Column Range ('rng').
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(DateColumn)
    ' Apply formatting to Date Column Range.
    rng.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" ' "dd\/mm\/yyyy" for international.

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Number format applied.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub

Sub IOnlyKnowTheColumnTitle()
    
    Const Header As String = "Date"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    ' Define Header Row Range (Headers, Titles).
    Dim hRng As Range
    Set hRng = tbl.HeaderRowRange
    
    ' Try to calculate the Date Column Number.
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Temp = Application.Match(Header, hRng, 0)
    
    If Not IsError(DateColumn) Then
        ' Define Date Column.
        Dim DateColumn As Long
        DateColumn = CLng(Temp)
        ' Define Date Column Range ('rng').
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(DateColumn)
        ' Apply formatting to Data Column Range.
        rng.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" ' "dd\/mm\/yyyy" for international.
        ' Inform user.
        MsgBox "Number format applied.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        ' inform user.
        MsgBox "Could not find '" & Header & "' column.", vbExclamation, "Fail"
    End If

End Sub
```